# Mvc Ajax post from check-boxes in partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a partial view which is used to show a checkbox in a column of table in razor. When I click on any checkbox in the table its posting back to controller with Id of first row and not the Id of row in which the check-box is contained. The javascript function to post ajax request is "SaveChanges" as given below. 
The hidden field "RecurrenceScheduleId" is the primary key id.

Am I doing something wrong here?

**- Following are my view & controller action:**

```
  @model SMRDS.Model.RecurrenceSchedule

  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_LogOccurancePartial", "Schedule",
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                UpdateTargetId = "tdOccurance",
                HttpMethod = "post",
                LoadingElementId = "btnProgress",
                OnBegin = "dialogBegin",
                OnSuccess = "updateSuccess",
                OnFailure = "dialogFailure"
            },
            new { id = "frm-toggle" }))
           {

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RecurrenceScheduleId)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.LogOccurences, new { @onclick ="SaveChanges(this)" })
            }
<script> 

function updateSuccess() {}

function dialogFailure() {}

function dialogComplete() {}

function dialogBegin() {}

function SaveChanges(checkboxInput) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Schedule/_LogOccurancePartial',
        data: { newValue: checkboxInput.checked, id: $("#RecurrenceScheduleId").val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
           //handle success
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller Action :**

```
 public JsonResult _LogOccurancePartial(bool newValue,int id)
 { 
        var result = BLL.Service.RecurrenceSchedules.UpdateLogOccurence(id, newValue);

        return Json(new { result = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

**Update**

Following is the html rendered for hidden fields.  At present I have only two rows with Ids "40" & "41".

```
<input data-val="true" id="RecurrenceScheduleId"
    name="RecurrenceScheduleId" type="hidden" value="40"> 

<input data-val="true" id="RecurrenceScheduleId"
    name="RecurrenceScheduleId" type="hidden" value="41">
```

Comment: Do you have duplicate ids in your rendered html?

Comment: @Jasen , following is the html rendered for hidden fields. At present I have only two rows with Ids "40" & "41". <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field RecurrenceScheduleId must be a number." data-val-required="The RecurrenceScheduleId field is required." id="RecurrenceScheduleId" name="RecurrenceScheduleId" type="hidden" value="40">   <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field RecurrenceScheduleId must be a number." data-val-required="The RecurrenceScheduleId field is required." id="RecurrenceScheduleId" name="RecurrenceScheduleId" type="hidden" value="41">

Comment: You should edit that into your question. It will be easier to read.

Comment: Element `id` attribute values must be unique. You have duplicated "RecurrenceScheduleId".

Comment: Right, but I have used  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RecurrenceScheduleId)  for id fields so they are same. Is there a way by which I can associate id also with the checkbox which is bound to a Boolean property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your responsibility to maintain unique ids when you use the helpers.

If you had a model

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And your view contains a collection you can use a for loop with an index to override the id with unique values.

```
@model List<ViewModel>

@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Id, htmlAttributes: new { id = "item" + item.Id })    
}
```

But you can also adjust your click handler so you don't need to find a hidden input by id.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.LogOccurences,
    new { @class="trigger", data_rsid=m.RecurrenceScheduleId })

<script>
    $("body").on("click", ".trigger", function(e) {
        var rsId = $(this).data("rsid");
        var checked = $(this).prop("checked");
        var data = { newValue: checked, id: rsId }
        $.ajax({ ... });
    });
</script>
```